# LinearProgressIndicator in Flutter using Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, progress-bar, firebase-storage

How to make a download bar with LinearProgressIndicator with download data coming from Firebase Storage?
The function I'm currently using:

```
Future<int> downloadBuscaDB() async{
 String path = await dbManager.localPathFiles();
 String fileDBZip = ConstData.dbZip;
 FirebaseStorage storage = new FirebaseStorage();
 StorageReference ref = storage.ref().child(fileDBZip);
 StorageFileDownloadTask storageFileDownloadTask = ref.writeToFile(File('$path/$fileDBZip'));
 FileDownloadTaskSnapshot fileDownloadTaskSnapshot = await storageFileDownloadTask.future;
 int bCount = fileDownloadTaskSnapshot.totalByteCount;
 return bCount;
}
```

Comment: Checkout this GitHub issue thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20803#issuecomment-437726304.   
In particular, it seems the even snapshot can provide you with bytes transferred and total bytes: `_progress = event.snapshot.bytesTransferred.toDouble() / event.snapshot.totalByteCount.toDouble();`

Comment: Could you please give me an example? I can only get the total bytes.

Comment: What version of flutter and the firestore plugin are you using? It would also help if you provided an example of what you've tried.

Comment: //  firebase_storage: 1.0.4 // flutter 1.0

Comment: I can only bring the total bytes

Comment: Looked into this again this morning and found the same issue on my end. You can get upload progress it seems but not download progress.

Answer (score 0):

firebase_storage has [TaskSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/TaskSnapshot-class.html) `bytesTransferred` and `totalBytes` that you can use to calculate and display the task progress.

```dart
StreamBuilder<firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot>(
  stream: task.snapshotEvents,
  builder: (
    BuildContext context,
    AsyncSnapshot<firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot> asyncSnapshot,
  ) { 
    if (!asyncSnapshot.hasError && snapshot != null) {
      debugPrint('Progress: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}/${snapshot.totalBytes}');
    }
  }
)
```

Similarly, the class can be used for tracking download progress.